# Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object

Tags: adminform

I have custom module storelocator. 
Tabs used in the admin form. Below code is used to add tabs in the admin form.

```
$this->addTab('form_section_general', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('clarion_storelocator')->__('General'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('clarion_storelocator')->__('General'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('clarion_storelocator/adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

      $this->addTab('form_section_google_map', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('clarion_storelocator')->__('Google Map'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('clarion_storelocator')->__('Google Map'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('clarion_storelocator/adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_googlemap')->toHtml(),
      ));
```

General tabs shows correctly. But gives error for the tab 'Google Map'.  Error that i am getting is : Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object.

Comment: you may try app/code/community/Clarion/Storelocator/Block/Adminhtml/Storelocator/Edit/Tab
change file name " Googlemap.PHP " to " Googlemap.php "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the block with alias `clarion_storelocator/adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_googlemap` exists.
Also make sure there is no upper case letter in the file name.

I have a feeling your block file is named `GoogleMap.php`.
If so, then rename it to `Googlemap.php` or change the your code to look like this:

```
'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('clarion_storelocator/adminhtml_storelocator_edit_tab_googleMap')->toHtml(),
```

Comment: Thanks. Issue was I used upper case letter in the file extension  like Googlemap.PHP

Answer (score 0):

You just rename this Google.PHP to Google.php under

```
app/code/community/Clarion/Storelocator/Block/Adminhtml/Storelocator/Edit/Tab/Googlemap.php.
```

The extension with all caps seems to be the problem.